# Python - How to join list of dictionaries itself

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have one list of dictionaries. Here is example :

```
list1 = 
[
    { "orgkey":"1", "id" : "0", "parent" : "#", "text" : "A" },
    { "orgkey":"2", "id" : "1", "parent" : "0", "text" : "B" },
    { "orgkey":"3", "id" : "2", "parent" : "1", "text" : "C" },
]
```

How i can merge this list by itself based on "orgkey"?
What i expect is like this :

```
list_result = 
[
    { "id" : "0", "parent" : "#", "text" : "A", "data": {"orgkey": "1"} },
    { "id" : "1", "parent" : "0", "text" : "B", "data": {"orgkey": "2"} },
    { "id" : "2", "parent" : "1", "text" : "C", "data": {"orgkey": "3"} },
]
```

As info, i'm using python 3.8.8.
Thanks.

Comment: Something like `for dic in list1: dic["data"] = {"orgkey": dic["orgkey"]}; del dic["orgkey"]`?

Comment: I think you want to look at a `map()` of the list items or a comprehension

Comment: Why have a list of dict? `[{"id": 0, "id": 1, "id": 2}]` Why not just a dict? `{0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}}]`

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension to rebuild each dictionary should do the trick simply enough:

```
list1 = [
    { "orgkey":"1", "id" : "0", "parent" : "#", "text" : "A" },
    { "orgkey":"2", "id" : "1", "parent" : "0", "text" : "B" },
    { "orgkey":"3", "id" : "2", "parent" : "1", "text" : "C" },
]

list1 = [ {**d,"data":{"orgkey":d.pop("orgkey")}} for d in list1 ]

print(*list1,sep="\n")
{'id': '0', 'parent': '#', 'text': 'A', 'data': {'orgkey': '1'}}
{'id': '1', 'parent': '0', 'text': 'B', 'data': {'orgkey': '2'}}
{'id': '2', 'parent': '1', 'text': 'C', 'data': {'orgkey': '3'}}
```

How it works:

For each dictionary in the list (`d`), a new dictionary is created using the key/values of the original (`**d` means all key:value of `d`) in addition to a `"data"` key with a value that is a small dictionary with one key (`orgkey`) and a value that is taken out of `d` using `d.pop("orgkey")`.  Python executes the `d.pop("orgkey")` part before expanding the key values, so `**d` no longer contains "orgkey" when the new dictionary is assembled.

If you are using Python 3.9 or later, you can use the pipe (`|`) operator between dictionaries to combine the small `{"data":...}` dictionary with each of list items:

```
list1 = [ d | {"data":{"orgkey":d.pop("orgkey")}} for d in list1 ]
```

Comment: I like this answer, but you might want to include a little explanation of what `**dict` and `dict.pop()` are doing so a beginner can follow along rather than cut n' paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and add `data` field

```
list1 = [
    { "orgkey":"1", "id" : "0", "parent" : "#", "text" : "A" },
    { "orgkey":"2", "id" : "1", "parent" : "0", "text" : "B" },
    { "orgkey":"3", "id" : "2", "parent" : "1", "text" : "C" },
]

list_result = []

for item in list1:
    orgkey_value = item.pop('orgkey')
    item['data'] = {"orgkey": orgkey_value}
    list_result.append(item)

print(list_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should yield the result you want:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, List

def modify_by_key(key: str, my_list: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    for d in my_list:
        val = d.pop(key)
        d["data"] = {key: val}
    return my_list

list1 = [
    { "orgkey":"1", "id" : "0", "parent" : "#", "text" : "A" },
    { "orgkey":"2", "id" : "1", "parent" : "0", "text" : "B" },
    { "orgkey":"3", "id" : "2", "parent" : "1", "text" : "C" },
]

list_result = modify_by_key("orgkey", list1)
print(list_result)
>>> [{'id': '0', 'parent': '#', 'text': 'A', 'data': {'orgkey': '1'}}, {'id': '1', 'parent': '0', 'text': 'B', 'data': {'orgkey': '2'}}, {'id': '2', 'parent': '1', 'text': 'C', 'data': {'orgkey': '3'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code example to get the desired output

```
def get_result(list1):
    result = []
    for item in list1:
        item["data"] = {"orgkey": item["orgkey"]}
        result.append(item)
    return result

list_result = get_result(list1)
```

Here is an example of how the get_result() function can be used:

```
list1 = [
    { "orgkey":"1", "id" : "0", "parent" : "#", "text" : "A" },
    { "orgkey":"2", "id" : "1", "parent" : "0", "text" : "B" },
    { "orgkey":"3", "id" : "2", "parent" : "1", "text" : "C" },
]

list_result = get_result(list1)

print(list_result)
```

Then, the above code will return the desired result as below:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "A",
        "data": {
            "orgkey": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "parent": "0",
        "text": "B",
        "data": {
            "orgkey": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "parent": "1",
        "text": "C",
        "data": {
            "orgkey": "3"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the original data you can a copy of the dict and pop from that:

```
result = []
for d in list1:
   copy = dict(d)
   copy["data"] = {"orgkey": copy.pop("orgkey")}
   result.append(copy)
```

If you upgrade to python 3.9+ you can use the union operator on dicts allowing the use of the walrus operator and use a comprehension:

```
result = [(copy := dict(d)) | {"data": {"orgkey": copy.pop("orgkey")}} for d in list1]
```

Result

```
[
    {'id': '0', 'parent': '#', 'text': 'A', 'data': {'orgkey': '1'}},
    {'id': '1', 'parent': '0', 'text': 'B', 'data': {'orgkey': '2'}},
    {'id': '2', 'parent': '1', 'text': 'C', 'data': {'orgkey': '3'}}
]
```

Comment: walrus is not a good practice to use it. using multiple operations in a single line or one liner is also not a good practice.

Comment: @DejeneT. How is this not good practice? Its in the PEP [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#simplifying-list-comprehensions) and [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#special-casing-comprehensions)